# how to overlap two lines in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, line, buffer, overlapping-features, select-by-location

[image][image][image]enter image description here

I am working on QGIS 3.10 and would like to overlap two lines in order to use select by location tool. I tried all the option in this tool and get just a few data selected. As the two lines are not overlapping I will still have this issue. I created a buffer for one line but I still have a bit of the other line inside of it.  Is there any plugin or tool that will automatically overlap these two lines?

Comment: Please provide an image of your buffered and unbuffered data, as well as provide your exact settings for the `select by location` tool.

Comment: Use [Select within distance](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisselectwithindistance)